# Sidenotes package, can't solve TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [grouping levels=255]

Tags: sidenotes

The sidenotes package works pretty well, but I cant find a way to use the figure* environment. When I try:

```
 \documentclass{article}
 \usepackage{sidenotes}
 \usepackage{graphicx}
 \renewcommand{\footnote}{\sidenote}
 \renewcommand{\caption}{\sidecaption}


\begin{document}
\section{Title}\label{title}

Noice content. \sidenote{Sidenote}

\begin{figure*}
\centering
\includegraphics[]{fig.png}
\caption{Este é um sidecaption.}
\end{figure*}
\end{document}
```

I get:

```
<fig.png, id=1, 2248.4pt x 1585.925pt> <use fig.png>
! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [grouping levels=255].
\caption@addtofont #1#2->\begingroup 
                                     \expandafter \let \expandafter \caption...
l.17 \end
         {figure*}
!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
Transcript written on teste.log.
```

with:

```
pdflatex teste.tex
```

In order for that to become a MWE, just remove the caption within the figure* environment.

- What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Use \ includegraphics {example-image-a} to include an image. Of all the ways to remove the lines from the figure, I can not compile your file. Give the error:! Missing number, treated as zero.
<To be read again>
\ Tex_let: D... Apparently the package is broken with the updated versions of ltx3

Comment: Without the figure * environment you can not compile either \documentclass{article}
\usepackage{sidenotes}
\begin{document}

Noice content \sidenote{note}

\end{document}

Comment: The figure* environment comes with the sidenote package..

Comment: `figure*` does not make the difference, I have updated my version of TexLIve 2017 and commenting on those lines the file can not be compiled

Comment: I just tested here 'figure*' does make a difference. Are you sure you removed the \caption as suggested in the text? My pdflatex is running `pdfTeX 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.17 (TeX Live 2016/Arch Linux)'. Maybe that is related to the system I am running it in. The exact figure I am using is [here](https://transfer.sh/ooUYI/fig.png).

Comment: I think you should send an email to the author with the link to the solution proposed by @egreg

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It does warn you that something will go wrong:

```
Package caption Warning: \caption will not be redefined since it's already
(caption)                redefined by a document class or package which is
(caption)                unknown to the caption package.
See the caption package documentation for explanation.
```

and then it does go wrong.

In general if you load two attempts to redefine the same command then things will break: you are loading caption package and then redefine `\caption` by hand.

Just use `\sidecaption`

```
 \documentclass{article}
 \usepackage{sidenotes}
 \usepackage{graphicx}
 \renewcommand{\footnote}{\sidenote}
 %\renewcommand{\caption}{\sidecaption}


\begin{document}
\section{Title}\label{title}

Noice content. \sidenote{Sidenote}

\begin{figure*}
\centering
\includegraphics[]{fig.png}
\sidecaption{Este é um sidecaption.}
\end{figure*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This doesn't cure all the errors.

Comment: @egreg no, it still leaves poverty and world peace to fix.

Comment: `! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   \tex_let:D 
l.16 Noice content. \sidenote{Sidenote}
`

Comment: @egreg not in this MWE?

Comment: @Yes, the same MWE

Comment: It runs without error here (but some of my expl3 code is from development sources)

Answer (score 7):

It's a bug in `sidenotes.sty` that does

```
\NewDocumentCommand \@sidenotes@multisign { } {3sp}
```

which is conceptually wrong, as `\@sidenotes@multisign` is used in expandable context.

It's also wrong to do `\renewcommand{\caption}{\sidecaption}`, because it either makes `caption` into not working at all or creates an infinite loop.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{sidenotes}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\renewcommand{\footnote}{\sidenote}

\makeatletter
\ExplSyntaxOn
\tl_set:Nn \@sidenotes@multisign {3sp}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\section{Title}\label{title}

Noice content. \sidenote{Sidenote}

\begin{figure*}
\centering
\includegraphics[]{example-image}
\sidecaption{Este é um sidecaption.}
\end{figure*}
\end{document}
```

Actually, the package should be thoroughly rewritten.

Comment: Is there any easier way (from a regular user point of view) to set that value in a clean L3 way?

Comment: For example `\title{Wombat}` for `\maketitle`. What is the L3 approach here?

Comment: @Johannes_B I don't think that there are details on how the document level of L3 will look like. But I could imagine a keyval like setup: `\setdocumentproperties{ title = Wombat }`

Comment: @Johannes_B as far as `\@sidenotes@multisign` is concerned: this is an internal marker for the package which in L3 on the code level should be something like `\l__sidenotes_multisign_dim` and not be set by a user at all…

Comment: @Clemens How about a string i need to reuse? \documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse}

\newcommand{\foo}{foo}

\NewDocumentCommand{\Foo}{}{foo}



\begin{document}
\MakeUppercase{\foo}% Wird expandiert

\MakeUppercase{\Foo}% Nicht expandiert!


\end{document}

Comment: @Johannes_B you mean if you as a document author want to program something yourself? I haven't put much thought into that. But I'd imagine an implementation in expl3 on the code level and a proper document interface command that makes it unnecessary to use the variable itself after `\begin{document}` like in many examples here in tex.sx… in an ideal world a document author wouldn't need to do such things at all, though.

Comment: @clemens `\renewcommand{\chapterpagestyle}{headings}`  for example. Or resetting of headers/footers? It is common to change that stuff mid-document. Unfortunately, i still have T 15, so i cannot do any testing right now.

Comment: @clemens It's also a *very* bad idea to redefine `figure*` and `table*` to do very different things from what they're supposed to do in the standard setup.

Comment: @Johannes_B but this is common in L2e. In L3 the syntax will probably rather be along the lines of `\setdocumentproperties{ chapter-page-style = headings }`. But we shouldn't dsicuss this in the comment section here :)

Comment: @egreg fully agreed!